# Applescript click on multiple Google Chrome buttons - stopped working randomly

Tags: google-chrome, applescript

I was using a relatively simple applescript to automate clicking on two buttons in Google Chrome. It was working for weeks but has now stopped randomly without me changing anything. Here is the code I was using:

...

```
set loc1 to {1200, 400}
set loc2 to {1000, 600}

repeat 30 times
    tell application "System Events"
        tell process "Google Chrome"
            set newest to true
            delay 0.2
            click at loc1
            delay 0.1
            click at loc1
            delay 0.1
            click at loc2
        end tell
    end tell
end repeat
```

...

After some experimenting I can still click on the tabs at the top of the chrome browser, but I can no longer click on any buttons/elements on the webpage. Any thoughts on things I can try?

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

[@mrstuckguy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19117288/mrstuckguy), I see your question has no answer yet. I think you'd probably be better off just using Greasemonkey-style user scripts (JavaScript) to interact with HTML elements. Check [Tampermonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo?hl=en) for example. You have a lot of examples on the web of how to interact with HTML buttons such as those pesky [Cookie Banners](https://www.i-dont-care-about-cookies.eu). If you need help with an annoying popup just ask.

You'd add in a user scripts manager something like this:

```
setTimeout(() => {
   var elements = document.querySelectorAll('a-moving-target-button')
   elements.forEach((element) => {
      if (element.textContent == 'I Agree') { element.click() }
   })
},1000)
```

You should be aware, however, that the layout of these button-elements keeps changing and redact them respectively.